# Is this a bug with the visual studio compiler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types, visual-studio-2015, casting

Just for fun I decided to (temporarily) refactor some code I found so that it uses a more functional style. (I wanted to do everything in a single expression/statement).

```
public ZDecimal TotalInvCurrPGAValue
{
    get
    {
        ZDecimal result = 0m;
        foreach (PGA element in this.Where(x => !((IPGADataCorrection)x).IsDeletedOrBeingDeleted()))
        {
            result += element.US_InvCurrPGAValue;
        }
        return result;

        // This should be equivalent to the above
        return this
            .Where( x => !( (IPGADataCorrection)x ).IsDeletedOrBeingDeleted() )
            .Aggregate<PGA, ZDecimal>( 0m, (x, y) => x + y.US_InvCurrPGAValue );
    }
}
```

However I get an error. When I hover over the `y.US_InvCurrPGAValue` in my aggregate lambda, visual studio says

> 'ZDecimal' does not contain a definition for 'US_InvCurrPGAValue' and no extension method 'US_InvCurrPGAValue' accepting a first argument of type 'ZDecimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However the type of `y` is `PGA`, not `ZDecimal`. This is clearly and explicitly indicated in the type arguments for Aggregate (`.Aggregate<PGA,ZDecimal>`). In addition, visual studio actually recognises this fact, as when I hover over `y` it shows a tooltip which indicates that `y` is of type `PGA`. I tried manually casting just to see what would happen like so: `((PGA)y).US_InvCurrPGAValue` but then I get another error:

> Cannot convert type 'CargoWise.Types.ZDecimal' to 'Enterprise.Customs.US.Business.PGA'

So even though visual studio knows that `y` is of type `PGA`, sometimes it thinks that it is of type `ZDecimal`. It all seems a bit schizophrenic.

Do I need to do something? Or is this a bug in Visual Studio? or is something else going on? (If it is indeed a bug, is there an easy way to report it?)

Comment: I tried your code at my end and it works fine (with my own assumptions on the definitions of `PGA` and `ZDecimal`). Perhaps you're running issues caused by implicit conversions. Please post a minimal case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: A problem might be caused by the fact you're supplying a `System.Decimal` value for the first argument when it's typed as `ZDecimal` in the generic instantiation. Change it to `(ZDecimal)0m` and see what happens.

Comment: Note that you should generally avoid implicit conversions. Can you tell us what the purpose of `ZDecimal` is and why you can't use `System.Decimal` instead?

Comment: Note that you can also provide explicit types for lambda arguments too, e.g. `(ZDecimal x, PGA y) => x + y.US_InvCurPGAValue`) which can help pin-down issues with generic type arguments.

Comment: Finally, please use the established .NET naming and casing conventions with your types and members :)

Comment: Yeah I copied the code to a new solution and made some dummy classes to see what would happen and the errors seemed to go away. very weird that it doesn't work directly in the original solution though

Comment: ZDecimal is just a company internal type which has some extra functionality. I'm not sure why it's being used in this particular instance